# Browserify exports with multiple entries

Tags: gulp, browserify

**TL;DR**: how to make multiple exports in browserify per entry file?

I have a [custom gulp task](https://pastebin.com/EP6BJQ6H) to build standalone library for AngularJS using browserify.

Configs looks like that:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        name: 'bbShell',
        styles: 'styles',
        standalone: 'bb.shell',
        export: 'bb.shell'
    },

    file: {
        lib: [
            'bower_components/signalr/*.js', 
            'node_modules/powerbi-client/dist/**/*'
        ]
    },

    browserify: {
        entries: [ 
            './temp/shell-html.min.js',
            './src/index.ts',
        ]
    },
};
```

So I define multiple entry points and deal with it in build script. It's ok with a single file, but when I have multiple entry points it seems like browserify export just a single one:

```
(function(f) {
    if (typeof exports === "object" && typeof module !== "undefined") {
        module.exports = f();
    } else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define([], f);
    } else {
        var g;
        if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
            g = window;
        } else if (typeof global !== "undefined") {
            g = global;
        } else if (typeof self !== "undefined") {
            g = self;
        } else {
            g = this;
        }
        (g.bb || (g.bb = {})).shell = f();
    }
})(function() {
    var define, module, exports;
    return function() {
    ...
    }()({1: ..., 2: ...
    }, {}, [ 174, 88 ])(174);
    // 174 represents 'shell-html.min.js' and 88 is 'index.ts'
    // should be (174,88), but (174) generated
});
```

Order doesn't matter, it geterate bundle with single js file export, but if 'shell-html.min.js' not included into bundle - everything is ok.